# how to set environment variables in Yosemite

Tags: macos, environment-variables, osx-yosemite

This question has been asked before but the solutions assume that you are acquainted with OS X, unfortunately  I'm not, so please bear with me. I would like to use `qmake` from the terminal command. With Yosemite, I'm not able to find an easy way to do it. The solution is suggested [here](http://www.jochenhebbrecht.be/site/2015-04-14/mac/os-x-1010-yosemite-and-environment-variables) but I can't figure out how to use it. The solution is as follows

> In previous releases of OS X (Mavericks, Mountain Lion, Lion, ...), environment variables are configured in the /etc/launchd.conf file.
>   As of OS X Yosemite, this is no longer working. To configure environment variables, you can do the following
>
> `$ nano ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.startup.plist`
>
> `my.startup.plist`
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>   <key>Label</key>
>   <string>my.startup</string>
>   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
>   <array>
>     <string>sh</string>
>     <string>-c</string>
>     <string>launchctl setenv $VARIABLE_NAME $VARIABLE_VALUE</string>
>   </array>
>   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
>   <true/>
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```

In my case, the path to `qmake` is `/Users/XXXX/Qt/5.4/clang_64/bin`, what should I do so that the `qmake` will be recognized in the terminal command?

Comment: So you just want to be able to type `qmake`? I.e., you want to add the path to qmake to your `PATH`?

Comment: @deceze, yes indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal sessions use the shell. You only should modify shell environment variables, there is no need to reconfigure GUI programs.

Also, I don't suppose the `.plist` offers a way to extend a preexisting variable.

You could use `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~XXXX/Qt/5.4/clang_64/bin
```

If Qt offers a more canonical method of installation, that would probably be preferable, though.

---

If you literally just want the command `qmake` to work, without really installing anything, just do

```
sudo ln -s ~/Qt/5.4/clang_64/bin/qmake /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: @CroCo It's applied every time you launch a shell. Until you change `.profile` again to remove it.

Comment: I got this `ln: /usr/local/bin: No such file or directory`